# getting a value error while executing the below code

Tags: python

My code:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,axes = plt.subplots(4,2,figsize=(12,15))
for idx,cat_col in enumerate(categorical_columns):
    row,col = idx//2,idx%2
    sns.countplot(x=cat_col,data=train_df,hue='Loan_Status',ax=axes[row,col])

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
```

The error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-693a2c827b5e> in <module>
      6 for idx,cat_col in enumerate(categorical_columns):
      7     row,col = idx//2,idx%2
----> 8     sns.countplot(x=cat_col,data=train_df,hue='Loan_Status',ax=axes[row,col])
      9 
     10 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in countplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, dodge, ax, **kwargs)
   3583         raise ValueError("Cannot pass values for both `x` and `y`")
   3584 
-> 3585     plotter = _CountPlotter(
   3586         x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   3587         estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, orient, color, palette, saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
   1582                  errwidth, capsize, dodge):
   1583         """Initialize the plotter."""
-> 1584         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient,
   1585                                  order, hue_order, units)
   1586         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    151                 if isinstance(var, str):
    152                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(var)
--> 153                     raise ValueError(err)
    154 
    155             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Loan_Status'
```

Comment: Seems there is something in your data that cannot be interpreted, how's your train_df looks like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a bit of feedback, if you change the title of your question to do more with your question itself, it's more likely to help other people who are encountering the same problem, and more likely to gather positive attention.